# Generating formats, compiling binaries

Tags: format-files

I compiled luatex from source, but I don't know how to install it. Running `build.sh` did result in the file `build/texk/web2c/luatex`. But simply placing this in `TeX/texbin` was not enough. The file INSTALL says:

> Post-compilation installation should be a simple matter of copying the
>   executable to a normal place for web2c binaries and generating the
>   desired formats.

But I don't know what generating a format means.

Comment: if you have copied the binary then `fmtutil-sys --all` will remake the formats in texlive but note that luatex 0.8x is radically completely incompatible with all previous versions of luatex the current format macro files for latex and plain tex as found in texlive will not work nor will graphics hyperref etc. there are development versions of most of these things but you need to be prepared for a lot of manual adjustments at the present time. Hopefully it will all go smoothly for texlive 2016, but there is a reason luatex 0.8x is _not_ in default distributions yet.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thank you! could I do this in a way that lets me revert to .80 easily; such as use a different name for the new binary? or could I put the old binary back and repeat `fmtutil-sys --all`?

Comment: you could do either of those, just putting the binary back and rebuilding is easiest, if you rename and have both binaries you'd have to build any formats by hand as fmtutil won't know about them (unless you configure that to know about your knew binary, which must be possible but i've never done that:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, this doesn't work for me, but, when I try to comp. a min. doc., produces: `This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.88.0 (TeX Live 2016/dev)
 restricted system commands enabled.

(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)%`

Comment: so your lualatex.fmt file does not match your luatex binary presumably you made a new binary and not remade the format. I can only suggest you revert to a clean texlive 2015 and use fmtutil-sys --all to remake all the formats, the current test luatex releases are absolutely not in a state where it is sensible to describe how to build them on a general forum like this. luatex 0.8x releases are for testing only (0.88 is already obsolete, I'm running 0.89.1 for example) If you do make a format, the latex packages currently known not to work include graphics, hyperref, amsmath, ifluatex,

Comment: Building formats by hand is (nowadays) quite a specialist thing to do, though forcing TeX Live/MiKTeX to rebuild them is easy enough. That would be a good question for the site. However, in this particular case things are more complex as the situation with LuaTeX v0.80-v.085-v0.87 changes is fluid and really is one for 'serious devs'. I'm not sure what can be said there beyond 'unless you are directly involved in development of LuaTeX/LaTeX/..., *do not do this*'.

Comment: All right; I was anxious to try luatex & curious, but will wait till the problem with Junicode has been fixed.